How to centrally align one character within a string in a frame/view?
I'd like to centrally align the numerical digit within a frame, so that the sign is ignored.
E.g. In a circular shape, I'd like to align the string "+9" so that the "9" is dead-centre and not the position between the "+" and the "9".
I used a ZSTACK to align the digit and the sign separately, but this is messy and fails when rendering on different devices with different screen estates, as well as Dynamic Type.
Here is example code - the red circle is with default alignment, the green with an approximate algorithm.
                let diam = 75.0
        
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 1, height: .infinity)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            
            // Aproximately correct!
            VStack {
                
                ForEach(9..<11) { i in
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: diam, height: diam)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                        
                        Text("\(i)")
                        Text("+").font(.title)
                            .frame(width: diam * 0.75, height: diam * 0.75, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(  .black).font(.title)
                }
                // Wrong!
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: diam, height: diam)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                    
                    Text("+23")
                }
                .foregroundColor(  .black).font(.title)
            }

        }


There has to be a better solution.

If you want the numerical part of the string to be centered (as opposed to the first digit, the title of the question confused me for a while), then this can be done using an HStack:

build the text as prefix + numeric part + prefix
the trailing part is kept hidden
use spacing: 0 to avoid gaps between the parts.

var body: some View {
    let vals = [9, 10, 23]
    let diam = 75.0

    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 1)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .foregroundStyle(.yellow)

        VStack {
            ForEach(vals, id: \.self) { i in
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: diam, height: diam)
                        .foregroundStyle(.green)
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("+")
                        Text("\(i)")
                        Text("+").hidden()
                    }
                }
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}



.hidden is a useful hint. Is there a way of squishing text strings together to remove spaces. I tried padding(0) but that didn't work.
HStack { Text("+") Text(i) Text("+").hidden() }
Then the "+" (or "-") is balanced out and the count is numerical part is exactly in the middle

@alanrick Ah, I thought you wanted the first digit to be centered. If you actually want the numerical part to be centered then yes, adding a trailing "+" with .hidden should do it. To avoid gaps between the parts, be sure to add spacing: 0 to the HStack. Answer revised.

I'd hoped to tidy up the code and remove the HStack by using a string interpolation. I.e. Text("+\(i)\(Text("+").hidden())") but this gives an error message. Using other functions such as .bold doesn't have this effect. Strange. It appears that .hidden is special because it is @inlineable - for whatever reason.

@alanrick The modifier .bold() has a return type of Text, so this is why the result can be concatenated with other Text. However, the view modifier .hidden() has a return type of some View, which is why concatenation doesn't work in this case.

Excellent explanation. It also helps me understand what to look out for in the reference documentation. Many thanks for this pointer.

Using the .monospacedDigit() modifier will be helpful here. In most fonts, the digits will be slightly different widths. .monospacedDigit() gives you a version of a font with equal-width digits, so you can column-align numeric strings.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/monospaceddigit()

.monospaced is a good hint. If there was a way of balancing the single character "+" prefix with a hard blank then that would solve the problem. But I don't know how to include a hard-trailing-blank in the text string
Text(String("+\(i) ")).monospaced()
